# Mapping to List Object in Spring MVC when Page is not displayed by a Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to map the value from Front end to Back Bean which is a List. Now the problem is that the page/view is not displayed by a Spring controller it is a jsp which is being displayed by CMS(content management system). So I cant initialse List and add elements to it and pass as a mode attribute

This is how my bean looks

```
public class LodgingAvailabilityRequest implements Serializable
{
private List<GuestCount> guestCounts = new ArrayList<GuestCount>();
public List<GuestCount> getGuestCounts() {
    return guestCounts;
}
public void setGuestCounts(List<GuestCount> guestCounts) {
    this.guestCounts = guestCounts;
}
```

and the GuestCount has the count field

```
public class GuestCount implements Serializable
{
private Double count;
```

this is how my JSP looks like

```
<jsp:useBean id="lodgingAvailability" class="com.pegasus.gen.LodgingAvailabilityRequest" scope="request"/>
<jsp:useBean id="guestCount" class="com.pegasus.gen.GuestCount" scope="request"/>

<body>
          <form:form method="POST" action="/lodgingbyroom" modelAttribute="lodgingAvailability">
              <table>
                   <tr>
                            <td>Count: <form:input path=guestCounts[0].count /></td>
                        </tr>
                     <td><input type="submit" value="Submit lodgingAvailability request by ROOM type"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
```

Now using above code gives me Array Out of Bounds exception so I tried couple of things as mentioned in some other posts

1. Changed to this  `<td>Count: <form:input path="${guestCounts[0].count}" /></td>` I dont get any compilation error but the vaue in controller is not getting mapped. The list is empty.
2. Added a for loop but this didnt work as expected since the list is empty and it wont enter the loop.

```html
    <c:forEach items="${lodgingAvailability.guestCounts}" varStatus="counter">
                      <tr>
                         <td>Count: <form:input path="guestCounts[${counter.index}].count" /></td>
                     </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

This is how my controller looks, where the form gets submitted

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/lodgingbyroom", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String lodgingAvailabilityByRoom(ModelMap model, LodgingAvailabilityRequest request,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    final Map<String, List<DXARoom>> groupByRoom = restTemplate
            .postForEntity(pegasusPath + "/lodgingbyroom", request, Map.class).getBody();
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("pegasusResponse", groupByRoom);
```

}

Comment: can you please post your controller code

Comment: I have added the controller, however I was able to fix the problem.See my answer !

Answer (score 0):

I was able to Fix the above problem. Since the list was not having any elements in it the only way to make it work is add a dummy element to list. So you can traverse the list and then map the values

**<% lodgingAvailability.getGuestCounts().add(guestCount) ;%>**

```
       <% lodgingAvailability.getGuestCounts().add(guestCount) ;%>  

  <c:forEach items="${lodgingAvailability.guestCounts}" varStatus="counter">
         <tr>
           <td>Count: <form:input path="guestCounts[${counter.index}].count" /></td>
          </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

for this piece of code to work make sure that you declare the beans

```
<jsp:useBean id="lodgingAvailability" class="com.pegasus.gen.LodgingAvailabilityRequest" scope="request"/>
<jsp:useBean id="guestCount" class="com.pegasus.gen.GuestCount" scope="request"/>
```

Comment: it's not good practice,  instead of adding **.add(guestCount)** in your jsp, if you  directly pass it through your controller  no need of using **jsp:useBean** because already your using jstl

Comment: Controller doesnt render this page, that is the problem. This page is being rendered by a CMS system and then I submit this page to controller.